# A good use for 18V alkaline battery pack

Tags: batteries, alkaline

I have some 18V alkaline battery packs that read 16V on a multimeter.  First question - are these still worth keeping? If so, I was wondering if there was a useful/fun use for them. LED light strip maybe?  Anything that would make an interesting home/shed project for a novice, don't mind spending a little money to buy tools and bits.  Each pack has 2 x 2-pin connectors to connect in parallel. Battery pack details (as read from the label) 18V / 30Ah / 540Wh.  Also have smaller packs 18V / 10Ah / 180Wh.  The packs were originally used for running an environmental recording device in the field.

Comment: As long you don't eat them or dispose them in the environment, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Excellent advice!  But I'll probably need more instruction than that. Any websites I should go to? don't really know what I'm doing but keen to use them for something.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Make sure to test battery voltage with some kind of load attached. Battery voltage reported without load attached can be very misleading.

Answer (score 3):

At an average of 1.33V /cell they still have about <20% SoC or juice left.

Answer (score 2):

You could disassemble one, and use the cells individually to power some ["joule thief"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief) kind of contraption.

[Novice friendly video by Big Clive](https://youtube.com/watch?v=K53beWYdIpcl)